# wso2 dashboard user information recovery

Tags: wso2, dashboard, forgot-password, wso2-identity-server

Does the WSO2 dashboard allow for User information recovery? I am looking at it currently, and documentation shows that it allows for users to log in and manage their account. Does the Dashboard also support User Information Recovery, (i.e. resetting the password or finding a forgotten username). And if it does, what values in the configuration file do I need to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Sort of. Here is a sample app that, I'm guessing, the WSO2 folks created.

http://cgchamath.blogspot.com/2013/12/password-recovery-with-wso2-identity.html

The example at the bottom has a readme with how to configure the server. What i did was to add a button to the dashboard login page that loaded the configured sample app, then rebranded the sample to make it look more like the dashboard page.